# Behavior of "Greater than" (and another inequality comparison operators) on arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I couldn't find any description or any mention about how `>`, `<`, `<=` and `>=` operators behave while comparing two arrays in javascript.

The only trivial thing I could think of is that the two arrays are compared by both elements for each relative indexes, but after testing it - I didn't got the result I expected.

So how arrays are being compared?

Few test cases:

```
console.log([1] > [2]); // FALSE - ok
console.log([2] > [1]); // TRUE - ok
console.log([2] > [2]); // FALSE - ok
console.log([1,2] > [2,3]); // FALSE - In case two elements in each index are compared, and the answer is "If all >" - ok  
console.log([2,2] > [1,1]); // TRUE - In case two elements in each index are compared, and the answer is "If all >" - ok
console.log([1,2] > [1,1]); // TRUE - In case two elements in each index are compared, and the answer is "If all >" - Unexpected
// More cases with 3 elements:
console.log([1,2,1] > [1,2,2]); // FALSE
console.log([1,1,1] > [1,1,2]); // FALSE
console.log([1,3,1] > [1,3,0]); // TRUE
console.log([1,1,1] > [1,1,2]); // FALSE
```

Comment: The operands of `>` are converted to strings if they're not either strings or numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @MohammadUsman Hi man, the question you referred is talking about equality only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the results of your test cases, you need to understand what happens when you compare arrays or any other object using any relational operator.

Long story short, **objects are converted to strings before they are compared using any of the relational operator**.

(*skip to the end of the answer if you don't want to read about object-to-primitive conversion*.)

#### ToPrimitive abstract operation

To convert objects to primitive values, javascript performs [toPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation that takes two arguments:

- `input`: object that should be converted to a primitive value
- `preferredType`: optional second argument that specifies the type that should be favoured when converting an object to a primitive value

For object to primitive conversion, [toPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation invokes another abstract operation known as [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive)

#### OrdinaryToPrimitive abstract operation

For object to primitive conversion, [toPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation invokes [`OrdinaryToPrimitive`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) abstract operation with two arguments:

- `O`: object that should be converted to a primitive value
- `hint`: type that should be favored when converting the object to a primitive value

[toPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation sets the `hint` as following:

- If the `preferredType` is a `string`, set `hint` to `string`
- If the `preferredType` is a `number`, set `hint` to `number`
- If `preferredType` is not specified, set `hint` to `number`

[OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) abstract operation uses following three algorithms to convert the object to a primitive value:

- **prefer-string:** If `hint` is `string`, return a primitive value, preferring a string value, if conversion to string is possible
- **prefer-number:** If `hint` is `number`, return a primitive value, preferring a number value, if conversion to number is possible
- **no-preference:** This algorithm expresses no preference about what type of primitive value should be returned and lets the objects define what type of primitive value should be returned. If `hint` is `default` or there is no `hint`, this algorithm is used to convert an object to a primitive value.

  It allows objects to override the default `ToPrimitive` behavior. Among the built-in objects, only `Date` and `Symbol` objects override the default `ToPrimitive` behavior. `Date` and `Symbol` objects implement this algorithm as `prefer-string` whereas all the other built-in objects implement this algorithm as `prefer-number` (*Objects can override the default `ToPrimitive` behavior by implementing [Symbol.toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive#:%7E:text=The%20Symbol.,to%20a%20corresponding%20primitive%20value.) method*.)

All objects inherit two methods that are used to convert objects to primitive values. These two methods are:

- `.valueOf()`
- `.toString()`

object to primitive conversion involves calling above mentioned methods and the object to primitive conversion algorithms mentioned above, call these two methods in different order.

#### prefer-string

This algorithm first calls the `.toString()` method and if the resulting value is a primitive value, javascript uses the returned primitive value, even if it's not a string.

If the `.toString()` method doesn't exists or it returns an `object`, then `.valueOf()` method is called. If `.valueOf()` method returns a primitive value, then that value is used otherwise `TypeError` is thrown.

#### prefer-number

Only difference between this algorithm and `prefer-string` is that it first invokes `.valueOf()` method and then `.toString()` method.

#### no-preference

When there is no *preferred type* or *hint* or if the *preferred type* is `default`, by default, `prefer-number` algorithm is used.

Objects can override this behaviour and of all the built-in objects, only `Date` and `Symbol` override this default `ToPrimitive` conversion behaviour. `Date` and `Symbol` use `prefer-string` algorithm when there is no *preferred type* or a *hint* or the *preferred type* is default.

---

**Now coming back to you question**, relational operators, i.e. `<, >=, <, <=` can be used to compare strings as well as numbers. If either operand of these operators is an `object`, it is converted to primitive value using `prefer-number` algorithm. So when you compare two arrays using a relational operator, javascript tries to convert each array into a primitive value using `prefer-number` algorithm.

As mentioned above, `prefer-number` algorithm first calls `.valueOf()` method. If return value is a primitive value, that value is used, otherwise `.toString()` method is called.

Default implementation of `.valueOf()` method simply returns the object itself rather than returning a primitive value, so javascript always ends up calling `.toString()` method when it uses `prefer-number` algorithm.

When `.toValue()` method is called on an array, it simply returns the array on which this method was called. Javascript then calls `.toString()` method on this returned array. When `.toString()` method is called on an array, it converts all the elements of the array into strings and then joins all the strings together with commas in between each string.

So when you compare `[1] > [2]`, you are comparing `'1' > '2'` and similarly `[1,2] > [1,1]` is converted to `'1,2' > '1,1'`.

As strings are compared by their unicode code points, `'1' > '2'` evaluates to `false` and `'1,2' > '1,1'` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

The arrays are converted to strings by calling the [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method before comparing, which acts the same as [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with no arguments.

String comparison works by comparing the code points of each character of both strings sequentially.

Comment: Really it is the internal `toString()` method and `join()` is similar but allows arguments

Comment: Oh ok.. And then they are compared as normal two strings (based on the values of the Unicode code points they contain) ?

Does it work the same with every other JS object?

Comment: Because I would expect `{"a":"b"}>{"a":"a"}` to return true, but it results false.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS Your question is about arrays, not objects. In any case, all objects become "[object Object]" when `toString` is called on them.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS No problem.